# How do I add text on my color picker in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this color picker and I wanted to add some plus sign or something like more colors text on my color picker how do I do that? For now there is this hyphen on the color picker:
[image: Current color picker]

```css
.more_colors {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  left: 2cm;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(152, 219, 43);
}
```

```html
<input class="more_colors" id="colorpicker" type="color" value="#e6f28a">
```

Comment: `placeholder` does not work for input color (May 2022) in Chrome based browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```css
.more_colors {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(152, 219, 43);
  margin: 10px;
}

.more_colors label {
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

.more_colors input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_colors" >
  <label for="colorpicker">Color Picker</label>
  <input id="colorpicker" type="color" value="#e6f28a" >
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) so you can understand that code only answers aren't very helpful.

Comment: This answers suggests positioning a label element over the color input.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<label>` to display text beside the input, since the input value is always a color (in hexadecimal format). Also remove the `padding` and `background-color` properties to visualize the color input changes:

```css
#colorpicker {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="color" id="colorpicker" value="#e6f28a">
  <label for="colorpicker">More Colors</label>
</div>
```